# XML の要素値を、テーブルビューのセルのテキストとして使うには

Tags: objective-c, ios8, tableview, xml

iPhone アプリを作成中です。

XML の要素値を、テーブルビューのセルのテキストとして使うにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

具体的には以下の通りです

- メソッド①で作成した `_iremono(NSString型)` の中身である XML の要素値を取得する
- メソッド②の中で、取得した要素値をテーブルビューのテキストとして使いたい

```objc
// ①要素値の発見時
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

　　　// 要素名の判別
　　　if ([_nowElem isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

　　　　　// 解析中の要素名(直近)としてのインスタンス変数「_nowElem」の型は
　　　　　//「NSMutableString」です。
　　　　　NSLog(@"要素値：%@", string);

　　　　　// 引数「string」の入れ物としてのインスタンス変数「_iremono」の型は
　　　　　//「NSString*」です。
　　　　　_iremono = string;

　　　}
}

// ②設定（セル）
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

　　　// セルオブジェクト設定
　　　UITableViewCell *cell =
　　　[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　forIndexPath:indexPath];


　　　// 設定（セル）※この「@"Inherent Vice"」の代わりに①で取得した要素値を入れたい
　　　cell.textLabel.text = @"Inherent Vice";
　　　cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


　　　return cell;
}
```

以上、どなたかご教示いただけないでしょうか。何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

_iremonoにxmlをパースした値を設定するところまでできているのであれば、
@"Inherent Vice"を_iremonoに変えるだけで良いのではないでしょうか？

```
cell.textLabel.text = _iremono;
```

もし、セル上に複数の要素を配置してあり、対象のラベルを取得できていないのであれば、
下記方法で取得できると思います。

```
// セルオブジェクト設定
UITableViewCell *cell =
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:<対象ラベルのtag>];
label.text = _iremono;
```

Answer (score 1):

XML、NSXMLParserとの関連を考える前に、UITableViewそのものに対する考察を、いまより深めるべきです。
**UITableViewは、それ自身にデータを保持する機構がありません**。たとえばUIImageViewならば、プロパティimageというものがあって、そこに自身の画像データを保持しています。ならば、UITableViewにも、プロパティdataのようなものがあって、自身のデータを保持していてもよさそうなものです。しかしそうなっていない。
「**MVCデザインパターン**」という考え方があります。ウィキペディアにも載ってるくらい普及している、プログラム開発の指針ですが、かんたんに説明すると、データ（Model）と表示（View）は、分離してそれぞれのオブジェクトにすべきであるという指針です。そしてiOSはこのMVCに準拠して構成されています。データと表示のオブジェクトを仲介するオブジェクトをコントローラ（Controller）といいますが、UIKit中名前に「Controller」がつくクラスが多数見つかるのは、そういう理由です。
UITableViewがデータを内部に保持しないのは、このMVCに準拠した結果です。であれば、あなたもMVCにしたがうのが、無理のないアプリ設計につながるでしょう。
ビューオブジェクトはUITableView、コントローラはUIViewControllerあるいはUITableViewControllerとします。しぜんとそうなりますね。モデルオブジェクトは、いろいろなものをあてることができます。ひじょうにおおがかりで複雑なデータなら、CoreDataを使い、SQLiteなどのリレーショナルデータベースをモデルにすることになるでしょうし、データ保持のためのクラスを作成し、そのインスタンスを常駐させておく設計もできるでしょう。かんたんなものなら、NSMutableArrayのオブジェクトをモデルとするのが、手っ取り早いでしょう。
ここではViewControllerのインスタンス変数として、NSMutableArrayのインスタンス「dataArray」を作って、これをモデルオブジェクトとします。

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
　　　if ([_nowElem isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
          [dataArray addObject: string];
　　　}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
　　　UITableViewCell *cell =
　　　[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　forIndexPath:indexPath];
　　　cell.textLabel.text = dataArray[indexPath.row];
　　　cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

　　　return cell;
}
```

注：
サンプルコード中、Objective-C 2.0の新しい書式、NSArrayの簡略書式を使っています。

```
dataArray[indexPath.row];
```

簡略していない書式：

```
[dataArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
[dataArray addObject: string]についてログをとってみたのですが、
stringは通常どおり要素値が入ったのですが、dataArrayは(null)になってしまいました。この辺りをもう少し詳しくご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: いうまでもないことですが、NSMutableArray *dataArrayは、アプリ起動時（メソッドviewDidLoadとか）に、初期化しておかなければいけませんよ。
`- (void)viewDidLoad {` 
`    dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];` 
`}`